# Error con ´Axios nodeJs´ no responde correctamente pero con postman la respuesta sí es satisfactoria, cual seria el error en este caso?

Tags: nodejs, axios, postman, headers, requests

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando consumir una API rest con la librería de `axios` el servicio que estoy consumiendo responde con un status `200` pero me arroja un error `[ "Bad request ..." ]` es un error controlado por el servidor, pero cuando consumo el mismo servicio por el entorno de pruebas de postman el servicio me responde también con un status ´200´ pero la respuesta del body esta respondiendo con los resultados satisfactorios, ejemplo `{
state: true,
message: "Registro exitoso"
}`, este es el problema actual.

Este es mi código:

Código en node

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = "http://localhost:8080/myServices/pay";
const objectPay = {
    "encrypted_data": "b62W+C1A3tWSnq7AsjiWlv4btpeXsuVcl/9Hjlud6QyZdgB3WFm9I9E0DbEIZODiRJ0+BZCIdNJpE40dAPnQeMVtRRhuPy6z++NWPz1zVflyNEyYgQFRBk3JtiYNAA78undY02hElyShomD00iSjsAYHWLErc5FdDInf9VwR1FSVadmOipqyefGqGXlcIZQY2+6tkBSehuiJLtpSXnwh0SWTM8rrraE5NLsXp/ZkPnDeRqinjAhlshFqKBsYrRoh0nS20RBYV3zjJGEMYcWk43jPiwYl8Bzb2VnHKf7SprCjCJaBjx3tO+486QfiSL1xXwqKfF8HGxQwcCt03wecXA==",
    "token": "WERWER53fhjASDu23424hasj383F"
};
axios.post(url, objectPay)
    .then((result) => {
       console.log(result); // [ "Bad request ..." ]
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     });
```

Hago esta misma petición por postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me responde ok, con la respuesta esperada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.) Por qué sucede esta acción con la librería `axios`?.

2.) A caso hay que modificar los headers de la petición con `axios`?

3.) `Axios` que no hace en la petición que sí haga postman?

Llevo bastante tiempo intentando solucionar este error, pero no he podido dar con el problema, pido su colaboración, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa los headers que envias o utiliza fetch.

Ejemplo.

```
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api';
// The data we are going to send in our request
let data = {
    name: 'Sara'
}
// The parameters we are gonna pass to the fetch function
let fetchData = { 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: data,
    headers: new Headers()
}
fetch(url, fetchData)
.then(function() {
    // Handle response you get from the server
});
```

> https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data#toc-handling-more-requests-like-post

Answer (score 0):

Después de hacer varias pruebas el error era el envío de las cookies en los headers de la petición, cuando uno hace una petición con postman el el envía unas cookies generadas por el servidor de postman, para solucionar el problema temporalmente lo único que hice fue copiar las cookies de postman y añadirla en la petición que se estaba realizando con `axios`, después de hacer eso todo funciono ok, la pregunta ahora seria. Como recuperar las cookies del servicio que estoy intentando consumir ?